# Python-syntax language as fast as C++?

Tags: c++, performance, jvm, programming-languages, compiler-optimization

This is basically a question "why high-level languages are slower than low-level".

It is known that high-level languages provide more human-friendly abstractions, but what does it have to do with runtime speed? Is it just because high-level languages are VM-based or because they're dynamically typed?

**So the question is:**
Would it be possible to achieve C++ speed if we'd create a language with Python syntax but without VM and automatic memory management?

Comment: With python syntax - sure, with its semantics - I seriously doubt that. If you try to create a compiler for all python features, sooner or later you will realize that you are writing an interpreter anyway.

Comment: C++ is very much a high-level language

Comment: It is actually the converse. Low-level languages are faster than high-level ones, but are much more difficult to use to write programs. This is why humans prefer high-level language to express more easily their intents.

Comment: Python user friendly syntax depends on memory management, and C++ speed depends on memory management. As this seems unsolvable, python’s speed is wildly linked to the default implementation, which isn’t the only one available. Also, there is a language that could interest you : Julia. Julia has a nice syntax, is able to include any already written python library, and reach C++ order of performance.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Using default compiler settings, Java (well-known for its VM and automatic memory management) can outperform C++ in various application classes.

Comment: What exactly is "Python syntax"? Using whitespace for structure? That's not what makes Python slow. A critical part of Python's slowness is that its exact, detailed syntax is runtime accessible via `Lib/ast.py`, which means that it requires a VM.

Comment: Reminds me of http://blog.gmarceau.qc.ca/2009/05/speed-size-and-dependability-of.html . Speed is achievable in a VM with automatic memory management (e.g. java) and there are other languages with interesting combinations of runtime speed and concise code (ocaml, scala). Of course the landscape has changed somewhat in the 10+ years since.

Comment: “*why high-level languages are slower than low-level*”—because people keep up that myth and (if ever trying to back up that claim) pick specific examples where particular languages perform in a way that seems to fit.

Comment: You might be interested by project like [RPython](https://rpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) that translate a restricted part of Python into C++. Translating RPython code to C++ is *extremely* slow and complex since RPython is higher-level language than C++. The PyPy team (who created RPython and the great PyPy Python JIT) also explain which part of Python make it so hard to get good performance (spoiler: dynamic types, garbage collection, high-level features, parallelism, etc.).